# What's the index (or topological charge) of this vector field image?

Tags: vector-fields, topology, research-level, weyl-semimetal

I am doing some research in a condensed matter system, and found this Berry curvature / vector field configuration that is unusual. I cannot find another example of something similar, either from physics or [math examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675722/how-one-can-calculate-index-from-the-figure-of-vector-field). To me it looks like a i=+2 that had another half turn added to one side.

[image: weird vector field]

Answer (score 3):

It could make sense for a nematic liquid crystal, where $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ correspond to the same state. Otherwise the configuration is discontinuous and does not have a winding number. Where did you get  this  particular configuration?

Comment: It's a Weyl semimetal at a critical point where two nodes of the same charge have just met, so that may explain the discontinuity. The system has pseudospin degrees of freedom, so there is a pseudospin texture associated with the Berry curvature field.